# Did the Hobbits of the Fellowship of the Ring wear hats?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, hobbits

From Bilbo's departure in *The Hobbit*, it follows that going on a trip without a hat was unusual. Hats were commonplace in the Shire: for example, when Pippin and Merry returned to the Shire as small giants, they were asked about their hat sizes.

However, I don't remember the novel ever referring to the hats that Hobbits should wear during their adventure.

Comment: "*The Shirriffs was the name that the Hobbits gave to their police, or the nearest equivalent that they possessed. They had, of course, no uniforms (such things being quite unknown), only a feather **in their caps**; and they were in practice rather haywards than policemen, more concerned with the strayings of beasts than of people. There were in all the Shire only twelve of them, three in each Farthing, for Inside Work. A rather larger body, varying at need, was employed to 'beat the bounds', and to see that Outsiders of any kind, great or small, did not make themselves a nuisance."*

Comment: Just so you know, this isn't the final form I hope the answer to take, when I get some more time to plan I hope to edit it and make it neater.

Comment: @Edlothiad OK. Am I suposed to "unaccept" your answer until you improve it, or is fine to leave it like this? :-)

Comment: Nah you can leave it, I was just letting you know. The content is staying the same, I just want to restructure because I feel it is messy.

Comment: It is remarked in *The Hobbit* that Bilbo *didn't* have a hat when he got to Beorn's house, and so couldn't raise it in politeness. So this seems to have been an accepted and known custom in the Shire, and one might expect hats were not unknown there in the well-to-do parts of society (cf Sam's shapeless felt hat)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### There is no mention of Hobbits wearing hats in the *Lord of the Rings*

I have searched my copies for the words *"hat"* and *"hats"*, and never are the Hobbits mentioned to be wearing hats during the events of the *Lord of the Rings*.<sup>1</sup>  As such, it seems unclear whether or not they were wearing or weren't wearing hats.

NB: This does not mean that Hobbits, in their daily lives did not wear hats, such as the Shirrifs pointed out by Valorum.

There are two characters in the *Lord of the Rings* that wear hats. Namely, Gandalf and Tom Bombadil.

> There was another burst of song, and then suddenly, hopping and dancing along the path, there appeared above the reeds an old battered hat with a tall crown and a long blue feather stuck in the band.
> <sub>Book 1, Chapter VI: The Old Forest</sub>

> Arrows  fell  among  them.  One  struck  Frodo  and  sprang  back.  Another pierced Gandalf’s hat and stuck there like a black feather.
> <sub>Book 2, Chapter V: The Bridge Of Khazad-dûm</sub>

Gandalf's hat is mentioned a few more times in *The Two Towers*, with no mention of hats in the *Return of the King*, before the chapter *Many Partings*.

The only mention of Hobbits and hats are the following three:

> '**Don’t let your heads get too big for your hats!** But if you don’t finish growing up soon, **you are going to find hats and clothes expensive.**’
> <sub>Book 6, Chapter VI: Many Partings</sub>

> He opened an eye and tried gallantly to smile. ‘Who’s this young giant with the loud voice?’ he whispered. ‘Not little Pippin! **What’s your size in hats now?**’
> <sub>Book 6, Chapter IX: The Grey Havens</sub>

### Sam's felt "hat"

In Three is Company, before Pippin, Frodo and Sam set out for Frodo's new home, Sam appears with a *"tall shapeless felt bag"* on his head, which he calls a *"hat"*. This is quite an interesting point, given the difference in status between the other two adventurers, Pippin and Frodo, and Sam. Sam is a lower class, more simple Hobbit. Gardener for Frodo, Sam may have chucked on the felt bag to feel more akin with his fellow travellers, who would have normally been seen with a cap of some kind.

---

Similarly, in the *History of the Lord of the Rings*, apart from the earliest works, the story talks of no mention of hats being worn by the Hobbits in the Fellowship. Although there is a very early version of the tale, where Frodo wears the Ring to escape from Maggot, and in the process temporarily steals Farmer Maggots hat.

Bar this, there is no mention of the Hobbits adventuring with a hat.

---

Some pictorial evidence from renowned Tolkien artists Alan Lee and John Howe, which may help shape viewpoints, show that the Hobbits likely were not wearing hats during their adventures:

[image: Homeward Bound] [image: Mount Doom]

More examples can be found below:

[Grey Havens - Alan Lee](https://tolkiengateway.net/w/images/3/34/Alan_Lee_-_Grey_Havens.jpg), [The Taming of Smeagol - Alan Lee](https://tolkiengateway.net/w/images/0/0d/Alan_Lee_-_The_Taming_of_Sm%C3%A9agol.jpg), [Shelob and Frodo - John Howe](https://www.john-howe.com/portfolio/gallery/data/media/21/127-Shelob-About-to-port.jpg), [Weathertop on the Horizon - John How](https://www.john-howe.com/portfolio/gallery/data/media/21/Weathertop-port.jpg), [Against the Shadow - John Howe](https://www.john-howe.com/portfolio/gallery/data/media/21/lotr_against-the-shadow_Confrontation.jpg), [Amon Hen - John Howe](https://www.john-howe.com/portfolio/gallery/data/media/21/sketchesAMON_HEN.jpg)

---

> <sup>1</sup> Did you search your copies for homburg, fedora, bycocket or bicoket, bicorne or tricorne, chapeau, bonnet, beret, biretta, boater (I just know there was a straw boater in Bored of the Rings), bowler, capotain, caubeen, cloche, deerstalker, fez, gatsby, hardee, kofia, porkpie, shako, slouch, taqiyah, toque, trilby, vueltiao, or any other of the numerous kinds of hats that do not bear 'hat' in their name? ;)
> <sub>[Comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192850/did-the-hobbits-of-the-fellowship-of-the-ring-wear-hats/192852?noredirect=1#comment528159_192852) by [@Lexible](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31393/lexible)</sub>

Based on this comment by @Lexible, stating my search terms were far too limited, I dove deeper, my results are below:

Homburg, Fedora, Bycocket, Bicoket, Bi/Tricorne, Chapeau, Bonnet, Beret, Biretta, Boater, Bowler, Capotain, Caubeen, Cloche, Deerstalker, Fez, Gatsby, Hardee, Kofia, Porkpie, Shako, Slouch, Taqiyah, Toque, Trilby, Vuelito: 0

Comment: Did you search your copies for homburg, fedora, bycocket or bicoket, bicorne or tricorne, chapeau, bonnet, beret, biretta, boater (I just *know* there was a straw boater in *Bored of the Rings*), bowler, capotain, caubeen, cloche, deerstalker, fez, gatsby, hardee, kofia, porkpie, shako, slouch, taqiyah, toque, trilby, vueltiao, or any other of the numerous kinds of hats that do not bear 'hat' in their name? ;)

Comment: I think you have your assumptions backwards. For someone writing in the 1940s - particularly one born in the 1890s - the wearing of hats out-of-doors would be an assumed thing. The mentionable thing would be if they *didn't*. Therefore - by your reasoning that Tolkien wouldn't have missed details - we can assume that if he didn't mention them being bare-headed, we can conclude that they did indeed have something on their head.

Comment: @R.M.: To second that. Thorin Oakenshield's hat in the Hobbit is only mentioned when it's useful to the plot. Several other hats appear in the surrounding paragraphs and are promptly forgotten again.

Comment: Not to mention that casually asking someone's hat size suggests that you expect him to know it (most likely because he frequently wears hats).

Comment: What about Samwise Gamgee? In the chapter *Three is Company*, it is stated that he "put on his head a tall shapeless felt bag, which he called a hat".

Comment: @JW, I've searched through 4 versions of the books, none of them have that line, can you tell me which copy of the books you found that line in, or whether it was from [this webpage](https://forums.signumuniversity.org/index.php?threads/hobbits-and-hats.555/)? And on commenting I find it, it is weird that didn't come up in my search... I'll look into it. Oh silly me, I was including spaces...

Comment: It's from the 2005 paperback edition of LotR, published by HarperCollins*Publishers* and occurs on page 70. I have it physically in front of me right now.

Comment: @R.M. while they may certainly have wore hats in their daily lives, and I'm not denying that, the evidence is quite strongly against them wearing hats during their adventure. Especially given all 4 hobbits at some time put on helmets, either without removing their hats or them not having hats.

Comment: @JW thank you for being persistent, I wrote this answer in a bit of a rush last night and seeing the quote, and not finding anything with a quick search made me think it was made up!

Comment: No problem. I was just fairly sure I recalled a reference to Sam wearing a hat around the time they were leaving Bag End, so I looked it up.

Comment: Not meaning to be overly critical of a well-researched and comprehensive answer, but while pictures from artists are certainly interesting to see, they seem to constitute weak evidence at best, assuming the artists in question did not communicate with the author on the matter of hat wearing. That said, I note that artist Angus McBride had a picture of the fellowship depicting Sam (and Gimli) with a hat, but the other hobbits without one.

Comment: @JW I chose these artists specifically because of their correspondence with Christopher Tolkien, and their repeated contracts to work on Tolkien's works. It is merely representative. I believe my stance is poorly portrayed in this answer, as I'm not strongly gunning for one side or the other. Merely that no hats were mentioned, so it's really up to you, as RM shows.

Comment: @R.M. It may be true that hats were generally assumed among most people at the time, but by that logic we would have to imagine almost everyone in LotR in a hat. Dwarves in hats, elves in hats, orcs in hats. Might as well stick one on Gollum. And, as much as I get a kick out of the idea, it might be a bit outside of what Tolkien intended. I think it's more of an an a la carte thing, where you can imagine them in with a hat or without one. Plus, even if the hobbits had hats, I feel like they be likely to lose em in Moria, or running away from the Nazgul.

Comment: @Joshua, did not all of the dwarves, and even Bilbo, wear hoods, not hats? Thorin's had a silver tassel. Gandalf wore a hat.

Comment: @MichaelFoster: Turns out I classify a hood not attached to a shirt as a kind of a hat, so I read right past hat vs hood in the discussion.

Comment: @R.M. you make a good point, but on the other hand, Tolkien was drawing from a mythos where hats were uncommon. Wagner's Ring cycle, vikings and celts... they did not war "hats", did they? Maybe hoods and helmets.

Answer (score 13):

> To the end of his days Bilbo could never remember how he found himself outside, without a hat, walking-stick or any money, or anything that he usually took when he went out.

We might then think that a hat is something that Bilbo Baggins usually took when he went out, presumably to wear.  While this quote from The Hobbit is about the absence of a hat, it is remarked as unusual.  So the having of a hat by a hobbit might be thought of as at least not unusual.

Oh, and Frodo, it turns out, made note of the same:

> He did not tell Gandalf, but as he was speaking a great desire to follow Bilbo flamed up in his heart - to follow Bilbo, and even perhaps to find him again. It was so strong that it overcame his fear: he could almost have run out there and then down the road without his hat, as Bilbo had done on a similar morning long ago.
>
> <sub>Book 1, Ch 2, The Shadow of the Past</sub>

Answer (score 4):

As Edlothiad had shown, there is no positive evidence that they wore hats.

I think that the fact that hats are not mentioned where it would be most logical to mention them makes it very probable that they were not there.

For example during the fight in the Chamber of Mazarbul Sam receives a light head wound from an orc blow. Would he had a hat on, somone (himself and narrator included) would remark on the damage to it. And when he splashed into the Anduin at Tol Brandir, it would float away.

Also they never use hats to wave for attention, nor are they lifted in greeting.

In conclusion, it seems plain to me that hats are usually worn by Hobbits while working outdoors, taking trips and walks in the Shire or participating on outdoor social events, but Frodo and his companions left them intentionally behind, knowing that these items would be a hindrance on the journey, and would soon be lost or destroyed. They probably used hooded cloaks instead.

Comment: Absence of a mention of a thing isn't proof of its absence. I'm struggling to remember any time that you see an elf pooping but that doesn't mean they don't poop

Comment: Of course not. If it would be, my answer would be superfluous, Edlothiad having settled the case. What I am trying to say that if Tolkien had imagined the hobbits to go journeing in hats (but did not told us because it was self-evident to him) he would likely still mention them when there is meaningful action related to them. As another example, Rohhirim probably do not wear hats. When Merry and Pippin greet Theoden, the cultural differences are emphasized in the narrative. Would they have hats, they would be described to lift and wave them in formal greeting

Comment: In 'Fog on the Barrow-Downs' it is explicitly mentioned "they halted and got out cloaks and hoods". Just prior to this the narrator mentions that "their hair hung lank and dripping on their foreheads". If they were wearing hats it is unlikely their hair would be hanging loose across their foreheads. Merry is described as being "cloaked", with a scarf, when he approaches Farmer Maggot and the others. In the Midgewater marshes the midges got into the Hobbits' hair (unlikely with hats on). After Lorien they had cloaks, but I can't find mention that they had hoods. Later some of them wore helms.

Comment: @Valorum it's common knowledge that elves don't poop.

Comment: As we saw from https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/132077/36526, Tolkien doesn't seem to have cared a lot about clothing in general.  The absence of hats in the written text does not necessarily mean a thing, aside from Tolkien neglecting to discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

In support of Ethlodiad's answer, which I find pretty comprehensive, we can look for further evidence: Tolkien's own drawings of Hobbits!

I had to resort to searching the web, since I don't own any of his books of illustrations. Some of his drawings are of Bilbo *within* his house, which of course wouldn't feature a hat because neither people nor Hobbits would wear them indoors:

[image]

However, I did manage to find an outdoors drawing of Bilbo, by Tolkien, and he is not wearing a hat. Now, this is a situation where one would normally put the hat away for fear of losing it, but I think the evidence is mounting and this is yet another indication Tolkien didn't envision Hobbits wearing hats while out on an adventure.

[image]

Comment: I know this is for The Hobbit, but I think it's evidence for how Tolkien envisioned Hobbit adventurers in general.

Comment: Unless their hats fell off.

Comment: @Valorum yes, haha, but we have to use Occam's Razor at some point. If every illustrator of Tolkien lore *and* Tolkien himself tended to draw Hobbits without hats in every situation (that they cared to illustrate), at some point we must admit the weight of evidence is too strong. (And no, we don't need to see elves pooping to assume they do... unless you can find a drawing by Tolkien! That would be a great find)

Comment: In "Conversation With Smaug" Bilbo appears to be bowing and holding a hat, but it could be also seen as him bending over and putting something in a bag... ( https://tolkienlibrary.com/press/images/22-ms-tolkein-drawings-30.jpg1555x2000.jpg )

Comment: @Yorik that's a good find! So maybe Hobbits do wear hats after all... You should make that an answer :)

Comment: Very good find.  Yes, this really does appear to be bowing and doffing a soft cap, akin to the sort of cap that Sam wore and called a hat.
https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Category:Images_by_J.R.R._Tolkien#/media/File:J.R.R._Tolkien_-_Conversation_with_Smaug_(large).jpg